# Why is my tensorflow generator function so slow?

Tags: deep-learning, generator, tensorflow2.0

Below generator function is too slow. Is there a way by which we can optimise this code ?.
train_dataset_c1 is train dataset for Class 1 of the form image,1
train_dataset_c0 is train dataset for Class 0 of the form image,0

```
def generator(positive_dataset, negative_dataset):
while True:
    for pos_rec, neg_rec in zip(positive_dataset, negative_dataset):
        pos_x, pos_y = pos_rec
        neg_x, neg_y = neg_rec
        x = tf.concat([pos_x, neg_x], axis=0)
        y = tf.concat([pos_y, neg_y], axis=0)
        yield x, y

train_generator = generator(train_dataset_c1, train_dataset_c0)
test_generator = generator(test_dataset_c1, test_dataset_c0)
```

Comment: What do you mean too slow?

Comment: Hey @MatiasValdenegro, When I try printing first few images from the test_generator it takes quite a bit of time. I am also curious about what would make test_generator slower compared to train_generator.
Btw I am using dataset.skip(n) in order to create test dataset and dataset.take(n) in order to create train.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using tensorflow 2.0 I'd recommend you using the tf.data API to speed up your pipeline.

Actually there is a [from_generator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) function that you can apply to your generator to speed it up

After converting it to a tf.data.Dataset object by using this function you can optimise it even more by using any strategy in this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance)